# How to show results of map<> written in Apex from LWC JS and HTML

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

This is my Apex Class:

```
public without sharing class VF_SurveyResponsePOC {
    public static Set<Id> setOfResponseId = new Set<Id>();
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable= true)
    public static  List<Map<string,String>> surveyname(string recid){
        //Map<Questionid, Map<QuestionName, ResponseValue>>
        Map<Id, Map<string,String>> MapOfSurvey = new Map<Id, Map<string,String>>();
        //Map<string,string> MapofInnerSurvey = new Map<string,string>();
        List<SurveyInvitation> var =  [SELECT Id,Test_Drive__c, ResponseStatus,  SurveyId,
                                       Name FROM SurveyInvitation where Test_Drive__c=: recid AND ResponseStatus = 'Completed'];
        system.debug('@@@VAR' +var);
        Set<Id> setOfSurveyId = new Set<Id>();
        for(SurveyInvitation newsurvey : var){
            if(newsurvey.Id != null){
                setOfSurveyId.add(newsurvey.Id );
            }
        }
        List<SurveyQuestionResponse> varnew = [SELECT  ResponseValue, Id, QuestionId, 
                                               ChoiceValue, InvitationId FROM SurveyQuestionResponse
                                               where InvitationId IN : setOfSurveyId];
        system.debug('@@@VARNEW' +varnew);
        Set<Id> setOfResponseId = new Set<Id>();
        for(SurveyQuestionResponse newResponse : varnew) {
            if(newResponse.Id !=null){
                setOfResponseId.add(newResponse.QuestionId);
            }
        }
        List<SurveyQuestion> varque = [SELECT  Id, QuestionName, Name FROM SurveyQuestion WHERE Id IN : setOfResponseId];
        for(SurveyQuestion newQuestion : varque) {
            if(newQuestion !=null) {
                //MapofInnerSurvey = null;
                Map<string,string> MapofInnerSurvey = new Map<string,string>();
                system.debug('##check map' +MapofInnerSurvey);
                for(SurveyQuestionResponse newQR : varnew ) {
                    if(newQuestion.Id == newQR.QuestionId){
                        MapofInnerSurvey.put(newQuestion.Name, newQR.ResponseValue);
                        System.debug('@@MapOfInnerEverything' +MapofInnerSurvey);
                        MapOfSurvey.put(newQuestion.Id,MapofInnerSurvey);
                        System.debug('@@MapOfEverything' +MapOfSurvey);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.debug('@check'+MapOfSurvey.values() );
        return MapOfSurvey.values();    
    }
}
```

[image: This is the format i am able to get in console.]

originalTarget: Array(6)
0:
**Overall, How Satisfied are you with your test drive experience with Vinfast ?**: "Very Dissatisfied"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {**Tell us why you are not satisfied. Which following areas did not meet your expectations?:** 'Vehicle Performance'}

**The Question is that. I want to show the Hightlighted part in one column and the non highlighted part in another column**. But whenever I am trying to fetch the key:value, The index of the value is taking as key rather than the question(highlighted part) and the value part is coming as [Object Object].

[image]
I have used nested map in apex class.
Need some help on this.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the JS/HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1):

This happens just because the target is an object with keys / values. Because LWC doesn't have anything similar to `object[key]` so you can't get values dynamically from an object if the key is not known.
So in order to show in on UI the data coming from the server needs to be flattened in a form that has known keys / values since we can do `{object.key}` to get values from an object.

This would look something like,

```
this.responses = responses.map(response => {
  const [[key, value]] = Object.entries(response);
  return ({ key, value });
});
```

You can also play with [this playground example](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/5PC27lQE3icFaOP8ZVNQ/) to understand it better.

To add you probably don't need to have `List<map<String, String>>`. Just because the questions are the key here. You can simply put all the questions to answer in a single map.